# in_array - prevent duplicate data in array

Tags: php

I have array:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'Roi' 
      'email' => string 'roi@pelegisr.com'
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'Roi' 
      'email' => string 'roi@pelegisr.com'
```

I would like to prevent duplicate data (email address) so I add condition:

```
if (!in_array($mainIndex['email'], $recip)) 
    $recip[] = array('name' => $name, 'email' => $mainIndex['email'] );
```

but duplicate email address still inserted to my array. why is that?

Comment: in_array` doesn't work this way, you need to check if multidimensional array contains duplicates somehow

Comment: can u give me example? - @kmlnvm

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$input = array(
    array(
        'name' => "test",
        'email' => "email@email.com",
    ),
    array(
        'name' => "test",
        'email' => "email@email.com",
    ),
    array(
        'name' => "test2",
        'email' => "email@email.com",
    ),
    array(
        'name' => "test",
        'email' => "email2@email.com",
    ),
);
$output = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $input)));
print_r($output);
```

it will work only if any row is equal(===) to another one

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
$clean = array();
foreach($mainIndex as $arr) {
    $clean['email'] = $clean['name'];
}   

$mainIndex = array();
foreach($clean as $email => $name) {
    $mainIndex[] = array('name' => $name, 'email' => $email);
}
unset($clean);
```

Or, when you load the data into the $mainIndex array in the first place, set the key to their email. This will automatically drop out duplicate results. This is a trick that comes in handy often. You're just repeatedly setting a key (which has to be unique by definition) to a given value. Multiple iterations end up with a unique data set.